# What to do to fix this select? The footer as well?

Tags: html, css, html-select, footer

I'm trying to write code for a sign-up page that requires country, gender info, etc. But for some reason my country selector isn't working in the sense that whenever I test it out, it comes back to me with plain text.

```
<h2>Please select a country</h2>
<select name="dropdown2"; required>
    <option value="afg">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="alb">Albania</option>
    <option value="dza">Algeria</option>
    <option value="and">Andorra</option>
    <!-- etc. -->
</select>
```

As far as I can see there's no errors in the code. But whenever I preview it, it doesn't come back to me correctly. The same happens for these two strips of code, for a footer:

CSS

```
.footer {
    border: black; 20px;
    float: center;
    background-color: light-tan;
    height: 45px;
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 500px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id ="footer"><h2>Site Map</h2>
    <p>Contact Us → Supported Languages <br>
    About Us → Help Us <br>
    Services → Website Copyright <br>
    </p>
</div>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Create a fiddle and share for quick solution

Comment: define `"it comes back to me with plain text."`

Comment: FYI There is no such thing as float: center

Comment: @Wim Mertens: I figured, but it did seem to work on Codecademy the other day so haha. Thanks for the FYI though. Maybe I just forgot that bit.

Answer (score 0):

This css is incorrect: `border: black; 20px;`
I'm guessing it needs to be `border: 20px solid black` ?

`float: center` doesn't exist. It's either `left`, `right` or `none`;

You have `id="footer"` but in your css you have it defined as a class `.footer`.

Not sure what you mean by the select being displayed incorrectly, you have `<select name="dropdown2"; required>` it will display but it isn't proper html.

Comment: Ah, okay. I couldn't decide if the footer should be defined as "class" or "id" for organization purposes. (I know it's a personal thing relevant to the code, but I would accept input on syntax if only to make it cleaner.)

Comment: And as for the dropdown menu: I copied the code from (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_forms.html) and modified it to fit what I was doing.

Comment: In html5 you can have <footer> as an element, but I'd still suggest to add an id or class. Whichever you use, it needs to be the same reference in the css. So if you have id="footer" then in your css you need to change it to #footer instead of .footer